# matplotlib-venn label text colour

Tags: matplotlib-venn

Pure visualization question:

I'm trying to adjust the font size and colour of the labels of a venn diagram made with `matplotlib-venn`.
I figured the font size can be adjusted with `v.get_label_by_id('11').set_size(size)` but I can't find an alternative for the colour.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to change font color for any desired color:

```
for text in v.set_labels:     # for external labels
    text.set_color("w")
for text in v.subset_labels:  # for internal labels
    text.set_color("w")
```